# Is there a recommended amount of attenuation for rectifying edge artefacts?

Tags: attenuation

I just noticed that Spotify fades in/out the music when you play/pause - is this to avoid clicking?

This attenuation is noticeable; is there a minimum amount of attenuation required to fix clicking (while not introducing a noticeable fade). Also, is there a type of attenuation that's best, linear, parabolic, etc?

On youtube, there's no noticeable attenuation, yet there's no clicking; could this be very small attenuation?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that for Spotify, it is not just about avoiding clicks, but also to improve the DJing kind of experience. The fade length seems to be a user setting in Spotify. Based on my testing with 20 Hz and 440 Hz test tones and [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/), YouTube doesn't fade in or out or do any other kind of click removal when pausing, here with 20 Hz test tone:

[image]

The worst-case test signal to be faded in or out would be a full-scale constant-valued signal (for 16-bit audio that would be 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, ...), because it has no audible sound of its own, and because it will still allow to hear the fade as loud as possible. Then we'd need the best possible fade shape, but I don't know what it is, so here is a sub-optimal fade in:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0&\text{if } x < 0,\\
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\pi x)&\text{if } 0 \le x \le 1,\\
1&\text{if } x > 1.\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

[image]

The following "floatbeat" program plays this fade twice a second (once in and once out per second):

```
f = function(x){return 0.5-0.5*cos(x*PI)}, fadeLength=0.03, loopLength=1, sampleRate=44100, p=(t/sampleRate)%loopLength, q=p-loopLength/2, (p < fadeLength? f(p/fadeLength): (q < 0)? 1: (q < fadeLength? 1-f(q/fadeLength): 0))
```

Try [running it](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html#t=1&e=0&s=44100&bb=5d00000100e00000000000000000330803a21341fb7c091be8a995e4a17efe5b97ab7f5d654b646d5c2584402d6736180a9e59a323772e096540d120e6efc5b19ae570b233e67d7a3bd9c1421f6867ef91a7937b12a940f05fe55c613ab66bdfe62f9b29b7fc51d1071711dd151c274caf09551c833ae793f53ff3a1e413eb9b920cee4e2886e378226611b262bb2f27a86ee7c767678f037e53f62c90d68f91ff872ce000) and adjust `fadeLength`. At least for me, using good headphones at normal music listening volume, a fade length 0.03 s is only barely audible as a thump, and increasing it to 0.04 s makes the thump disappear. **I think 0.03 s is pretty safe.**

But is 0.03 s already so long that it sounds like a fade? Let's apply the fades to a 400 Hz sine tone, in floatbeat:

```
f = function(x){return 0.5-0.5*cos(x*PI)}, fadeLength=0.03, loopLength=1, freq=400, sampleRate=44100, p=(t/sampleRate)%loopLength, q=p-loopLength/2, (p < fadeLength? f(p/fadeLength): (q < 0)? 1: (q < fadeLength? 1-f(q/fadeLength): 0))*sin(2*PI*t*freq/sampleRate)
```

[Running this](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html#t=1&e=0&s=44100&bb=5d00000100080100000000000000330803a21341fb7c091be8a995e4a17efe5b97ab7f5d654b646d5c2584402d6736180a9e59a323772e096540d120e6efc5b19ae570b233e67d7a3bd9c1421f6867ef9978ef0d0cc414228c9c3798db22698e4f1f4481bd41496167531792d9766e0b917d16c4c198ced59ee331d2c80138c9f7bb5850acab0c5f862df1209667cea62c124122904e885004e0ed856a4a00239c26f460b0ea7cf54d7f2e4dbceb74f2813541e2afe97deafef5ba29f5), I can't hear a click in fade in or fade out. I know there is a fade from the way it sounds and because I do a lot of music editing, but it does not register as a gradual process, more like a smooth event.

Let's try some other fade shapes of length 0.03 s too, with my comments comparing each to Eq. 1:

- Repeating Eq. 1 here [for easy clicking](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html#t=1&e=0&s=44100&bb=5d00000100e00000000000000000330803a21341fb7c091be8a995e4a17efe5b97ab7f5d654b646d5c2584402d6736180a9e59a323772e096540d120e6efc5b19ae570b233e67d7a3bd9c1421f6867ef91a7937b12a940f05fe55c613ab66bdfe62f9b29b7fc51d1071711dd151c274caf09551c833ae793f53ff3a1e413eb9b920cee4e2886e378226611b262bb2f27a86ee7c767678f037e53f62c90d68f91ff872ce000).
- A linear fade $f(x) = x$ [sounds](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html#t=1&e=0&s=44100&bb=5d00000100d00000000000000000330803a21341fb7c091be8a995e4a17efe5b97ab7f5d654b6d89288c8f4481fc048ef59710b5fa9b5ab3f7126c4f1091acb736ac7540e7e732981cd697c23a92402eb2625792777a00a13f63866ae9293af4d7b588e174aabd1026e30980dadb11fda97ab6813c9bd1add29de0b3132067858458963725a4628a2557f1edeb5b16ae31ffcbc16000) much clickier to me.
- Smoothstep $f(x) = 3x^2-2x^3$ [sounds](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html#t=1&e=0&s=44100&bb=5d00000100dc0000000000000000330803a21341fb7c091be8a995e4a17efe5b97ab7f5d654b64cc3d6ed4248214062c1eb87e82c6a6587157e7087710f38346e4010de61009a5d7c45cd840185ee7ad81d553818796d28b18a30cdf1f46e0399295a628f774f448443d1166511346f19808387d407be55935db741927ce89c9a5f9921d82fa21fff696370005834e586227964ff4c60e8508fef7db1100) maybe tiny bit worse to me.
- Asymmetrical polynpomial $f(x) = 6x^2 - 8x^3  + 3x^4$ [sounds](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html#t=1&e=0&s=44100&bb=5d00000100e60000000000000000330803a21341fb7c091be8a995e4a17efe5b97ab7f5d654b652b7426d424842d0132ae6781d32ff59e0345d5472e0a82cda04ba8a6615a11ed839b09968a74dcc8e9613c9e368a33f705abafc77b93919dd960cd6185928fd8d8fdd78be66347113537f8123b5e381c77adc3b2be23694fc06faedc16e4114e3e46a2275bb744e437043115545b58030de10bde0e87fef76a8f00) significantly thumpier.
- Smoothstep $f(x) = 10x^3-15x^4+6x^5$ [sounds](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/html5bytebeat/html5bytebeat.html#t=1&e=0&s=44100&bb=5d00000100ee0000000000000000330803a21341fb7c091be8a995e4a17efe5b97ab7f5d654b652b74285ef48a48cb89b44b5ef26af09419577ee13cd61a5bf2bc8fc200431b44ba2ac77490e58f2dd5f83986300a3d473735dca5b5d503418ea9e768899936791155686f22389ffc8553720adf2814d2b0b21c6fb3446dbd89ab2d45778993d44652d3436e1c55702f6fbc04dbe4ae34cb82a12eb84dffe4f40000) about as good, maybe even a bit better. Less mid-freq but more bassy thump.

Calculating the Fourier transform $F(f)$, where $f$ denotes frequency, of each fade of length 0.03 s appears to confirm what I heard: (For this, I calculated the Fourier transform of the derivative of each fade as function of time $t = \frac{x}{0.03s}$, and compensated for derivation by multiplying the result by a factor $-\frac{i}{f}$.)

[image]

I also included the pure tone hearing threshold curve from ISO 226:2003. Some caveats: I do not know the listening volume level so I just shifted the curve in dB scale until it matched my subjective hearing experience with the fade curves peaking above the threshold at roughly those frequencies at which I heard them. Also, the threshold curve has been measured for pure sinusoidal tones whereas here we are dealing with transient sounds. The level comparison between the two cannot be well defined. It would be better to do the analysis with something like a compressive gamma-chirp filter bank which better models hearing. I used closed-back headphones, but still my listening environment has some fan noise and such, so not perfect silence, so there could be some auditory masking going on. Despite all the caveats, I think the threshold curve is useful to show here as it seems to match what I heard. It also hints to that there may be a better fade shape that moves some of the energy from the first spectral side lobe to the main lobe, using [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) terminology. Perhaps a better fade shape, one that barely touches the hearing threshold at multiple early lobes, could be obtained by integrating a suitably parameterized Ultraspherical window. Or perhaps there are ways to trace the hearing threshold for all lobes.

I'd choose between 5th order smoothstep and Eq. 1, or 3rd order smoothstep if you want to save some processing power. The choice is not too critical.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. What do you mean by `full-magnitude constant-valued signal`? I'm thinking a signal of all 1s?

Comment: A signal of all ones is okay, theoretically, but be careful interpreting that through a real world sound system.  If there are any coupling capacitors in the circuit, the speaker location will not "remain at one", but will drift back towards center.

Comment: @CedronDawg my headphones go down to 10 Hz with about 3 dB of attenuation, should be fine.

Comment: @CedronDawg But good point, my computer built-in headphone out is not maybe the best thing to test with. Maybe I hear even more bass in 5th order smoothstep listening with a phone + headphones. Hard to tell.

Comment: I don't know what would be a better test. People like to think that the amplitude of a signal represents the speaker cone position. For a fluctuating signal, within operating range, that is generally true. The rule of thumb is electronics is that capacitors block DC and pass AC. So, at very low frequencies, the correlation isn't quite accurate.  Clicks are caused by discontinuities, which have high AC content in that sense.  Even discontinuities in the first derivative can have some "AC" content.  Other than that, I don't have much to add.  Well, one more thing, -1 to 1 would be a bigger jump.

Comment: Fades go 0 to 1 so that's realistic to test with. The needed fade length depends on the level so I tried to keep levels realistic.

Comment: No big deal, Olli.  I was just pointing out that if you were joining two signals with zero fade duration, that is your worst possible case.  If you fade to silence, then silence to signal, I am quite comfortable agreeing that the silence is at zero and 0 to 1 is your worst case.

Comment: Thank you for the list of smooth transitions

Comment: Hmm why the unupvote & downvote?

Comment: Tis should be accepted answer

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi does it answer your question? If yes, please consider marking it as accepted.